# What's a good VOIP application for 16.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, voip

I need to make some calls on my computer to regular phone numbers in the States from Mexico. What's a good and simple VOIP to use for that with the 16.04 distro? Thanks you much

Answer (score 2):

Skype changed to SkypeForLinux and now has some enhanced UI that is supposed to be better for the users. You might want to check that one out and also whether there are any problems in 32 bit mode.

Other than that there are a couple of other options you might want to check out the following. All of them support video calls and partially offer clients for all platforms including Linux:

- Viber for linux
- Jitsi
- Google Hangouts
- Google Duo
- Ring
- Firefox Hello
- Tox
- Facebook

Comment: Viber is for 64bit only.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Skype "on line". 
If you log in through Outlook.com [with your Skype account info] you'll be able to use Skype within Outlook. 
It has the advantage of being available on any device you use including when you're not at your own device.