# Is there a video program like facetime that I can download on my laptop, other than skype?

Tags: video

Receiving end is having issues with their skype, which works fine on my laptop running ubuntu. is there an app similar to facetime that I can download, to call their cell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good VOIP application for 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979628/whats-a-good-voip-application-for-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Discord](https://discordapp.com/).

It's targeted at gamers mostly but does a great job for videocalls.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of messengers, for example [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) - it also supports Skype protocol, or may be alternatives: Telegram, Watsapp, Viber - they all are crossplatform.